# Send funds via json rpc

Tags: ether, json-rpc

could anybody provide request to transfer some funds from one account to another, like this, but with sending some ether:
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getBalance","params":["0x712D30137644ca2a37BD0384CF0d881BB3aCbB31", "latest"],"id":1}' https://ropsten.infura.io/token
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the JSON rpc documenation:

```
params: [{
  "from": "0xb60e8dd61c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f07233155",
  "to": "0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f07244567",
  "gas": "0x76c0", // 30400,
  "gasPrice": "0x9184e72a000", // 10000000000000
  "value": "0x9184e72a", // 2441406250
  "data":"0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8d46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f072445675058bb8eb970870f072445675"
}]

curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_sendTransaction","params":[{see above}],"id":1}'
```

Comment: yes, but infura doesn't support sendTransaction method

Comment: only because the private key you'll want to use resides on your own machine, not infura's instance. sendRawTransaction works perfectly.

Comment: can you please provide concrete example, because I tried many examples, and all failed.

Comment: have you got solution @miller? If yes please share